# LSTMBlockFusedCell does not support using outputprojectionwrapper

Tags: python, performance, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I'm trying to replace `LSTMCell` with `LSTMBlockFusedCell` for better performance, but I have found that the `LSTMBlockFusedCell` does not have the project operation of the output so I have added the `outputprojectionwrapper` to the `LSTMBlockFusedCell` by

```py
cell = tf.contrib.rnn.OutputProjectionWrapper( 
    tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMBlockFusedCell(config.hidden_size,
                                      forget_bias=0.0,
                                      cell_clip=config.cell_clip,     
                                      use_peephole=config.use_peephole),
                                      output_size=n_outputs)
```

But I got an error

```
TypeError: The argument 'cell' (<tensorflow.contrib.rnn.python.ops.lstm_ops.LSTMBlockFusedCell
object at 0x7f2c08f1eb90>) is not an RNNCell: 'output_size' property is missing,
'state_size' property is missing, 'zero_state' method is missing.
```

How do I add projection in `LSTMBlockFusedCell`?